# What would be the best way to implement a CRON job in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

So I created a CRON job that is running properly and doing everything as it should, but my question is:
Is there a better way of building this CRON job to run faster or will this suffice based on an estimated user base of maybe a few thousand. I would essentially like to have it optimized, if possible or even needed since I will be running it every 5 minutes. I'm still a newbie when it comes to CRON jobs so any suggestions would be great, thanks.

```
$adQuery = "SELECT 
        ads.ad_id,
        ads.ad_date,
        ad_updates.ad_id,
        ad_updates.update_count,
        ad_updates.intervals,
        ad_updates.updates_left,
        ad_updates.Time_of_next_update
        FROM
            ads
        INNER JOIN
            ad_updates
        ON
            ads.ad_id = ad_updates.ad_id
    ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($adQuery);   
$stmt->execute();
$stmtFetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
  foreach($stmtFetch as $row){

    $id = $row['ad_id'];
    $update_count = $row['update_count'];
    $intervals = $row['intervals'];
    $updates_left = $row['updates_left'];
    $time_of_next_update = $row['Time_of_next_update'];

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if((strtotime($time_of_next_update) - strtotime($date)) <= 0){

        switch ($row['update_count']) {
            case 0:
                $update_count = '0';
                break;
            case 1:
                $update_count = '30';
                break;
            case 2:
                $update_count = '60';
                break;
            case 3:
                $update_count = '120';
                break;
            case 4:
                $update_count = '180';
                break;
            case 5:
                $update_count = '300';
                break;
            case 6:
                $update_count = '420';
                break;
            case 7:
                $update_count = '720';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        try{
            $query = "UPDATE ads, ad_updates 
                SET 
                    ads.ad_date = :date, 
                    ad_updates.updates_left = (ad_updates.updates_left - 1), 
                    ad_updates.Time_of_next_update =  (ad_updates.Time_of_next_update + INTERVAL $update_count MINUTE) 
                WHERE 
                    ads.ad_id = :id 
                AND 
                    ad_updates.ad_id = :id
                ";  

            $timeQuery = $conn->prepare($query);
            $timeQuery->bindParam(":date", $date);
            $timeQuery->bindParam(":id", $id);
            $timeQuery->execute();
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            print_r( $e );
        }

    }

    if($updates_left == 0){
        $deletequery = "DELETE FROM ad_updates WHERE ad_id = :id LIMIT 1";
        $deleteUpdate = $conn->prepare($deletequery);
        $deleteUpdate->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $deleteUpdate->execute();
    }
  }
 $conn = null;
}
```

Comment: MySQL have its own [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). I think  both CRON and PHP are excess.

Comment: @Akina MySQL does but I am running this website on Godaddy servers and they do not allow event scheduling without superuser privileges. They only allow CRON jobs. :(

Comment: If so implement everything as one stored procedure. And the whole job of your PHP program is to call this procedure.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into building a stored procedure and call that for the update. Thanks for the suggestion @Akina

Comment: Make sure your job finishes within 5 minutes i.e. before next one kicks in. or next one does not start if there is already an active one. Otherwise you would have a pile up of process if something goes wrong in DB.

Comment: @SameerNaik good to know, thanks. I will look into that and see what I can come up with.